# Discord.py Invite bot using bot

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

Im trying to make my bot to invite another bot using discord.py. Is there any salution to this? Thanks to everyone who's trying to help me out. Have a good one!

```
@bot.command()
async def Invite(ctx, invite_link=None):
    if invite_link == None:
        await ctx.message.author.send(embed=discord.Embed(
                        title='**Syntax Error**',
                        description='**Please provide an invite Link!**',
                        color=discord.Color.red()
                        )
        return
    #Inviting function
    #Doing stuff....
```

Comment: Maybe share a bit of code first ? 
We are here to help you out on existing code, not do it for you.

Comment: No I just need the one line that invites the bot. Im gonna do the rest at my own.

Comment: You don't share a code? We don't share knowledge, simple. We would need a starting point even though you could answer the question yourself.

Comment: Sure but do you mean that its not possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can only invite a discord bot to a discord server using the link that you will get from the [develeper portal](https://discord.com/developers/applications). Also, only a server admin/owner can invite a bot to a discord server. I hope this helps and feel free to reply to this message for more support!

Comment: So its impossible?

Comment: Well, yes. But you can easily make a command where the user will send something like ;link or ,link (etc.) and the bot will respond with the invite link. If you would like to do this in a hyperlink DM me at DRags#6969 and I will respond as soon as possible! By the way if you would like to know where you can get an invite link you can go to the developer portal: https://discord.com/developers/applications and go to "OAuth2" on your bot. Again, if you need any more help please DM me on discord at DRags#6969 !

Comment: Thanks I'll appreciate

Comment: Please mark this answer as solved if you understand.

Comment: Sure I'll do that. Thanks for your help tho

Comment: No Problem, I'm glad it helped :)